# check if parent field is filled then child field should also filled

Tags: angularjs

i think this is very simple but i couldn't find out a way..... :(

what i want is that, i want the **child field** should be filled **only if** the **parent field** is filled and also the **submit** button should disable if the criteria does not match.

i've tried it so far is :

```
<form name="frmApp">
  <input type="number" ng-model="parentField" />
  <input type="number" ng-model="childField" />

  <p ng-if="parentField != '' && childField == ''">both should be filled</p>
</form>

<a ng-disabled="frmApp.$invalid" class="btn btn-info">Submit</a>
```

[Demo JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jaym0403/9qPpQ/8/)

NOTE: **Either both should be filled OR none of them should be filled**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-required` and make it point to the `parentField` property to check if it's been filled

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app>
    <form name="frmApp">
      <input type="number" name="parentField" ng-model="parentField"/>
      <input type="number" name="childField" ng-model="childField" ng-required="parentField != null" />
      <p ng-if="frmApp.$invalid">both should be filled</p>
    </form>
    <a ng-disabled="frmApp.$invalid" class="btn btn-info">Submit</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This way, when `parentField` gets a value, the `ng-required` option changes for the child input. It looks a bit silly with `input type="number"`, you might want to add additional validation to see if there isn't bogus text in a number field - as text won't bind to the model with `input type="number"`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cX8Yt/1/)**